# SwiftDate returning relevantTime as nil

Tags: swift

I am using [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) to get human readable time in swift. Following is my code:

```
 var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(time/1000 ) )
 let (colloquial,relevantTime) = try! date.colloquialSinceNow()
```

Now the problem is that it is returning `colloquial` correctly but at the same time `relevantTime` is `nil`.

Here are the debug values of variables:

1. `time`: 1488799709000
2. `date`: 2017-03-06 11:28:29 +0000 (-    timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
   : 510492509.0)
3. `colloquial`: "17 minutes    ago"
4. `relevantTime`: nil

Comment: show us the `colloquialSinceNow()` method

Comment: have you set up the region? check [this test class](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/b8a6ace0b4a419d377886615ece14a3f259323fc/Tests/SwiftDateTests/TestDateInRegion%2BFormatter.swift)